# Set Make Homepage - REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, homepage

I have 300 site collections that I need to change the homepage, any ideas what endpoint there is for this in REST API ?

Comment: I know it's an old post but that's the only one I found so far. I'm trying to implement this using python and OAUTH. I have a valid token, and I'm able to do bunch of things (create sites, list sites, list site contents for my tenant), but I am not able to set the WelcomePage. I keep getting 403, Access Denied errors. I've tried without and with the X-RequestDigest header because it was not clear if I have to include it or not when using OAUTH token ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#writing-data-by-using-the-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can insert the below code in script editor to set a custom page as your default/welcome page :

**REST**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  SetDefaultPage();
});

function SetDefaultPage() {
    $.ajax
        ({
            // _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl - will give absolute URL of the site where you are running the code.
            // You can replace this with other site URL where you want to apply the function

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/rootfolder",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': {
                    // Type that you are modifying.
                    'type': 'SP.Folder'
                },

                // Specify Server relative URL of the page, you want to set as Home page
                'WelcomePage': 'SitePages/home.aspx'
            }),
            headers:
            {
             // Accept header: Specifies the format for response data from the server.
             "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             //Content-Type header: Specifies the format of the data that the client is sending to the server
             "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            // IF-MATCH header: Provides a way to verify that the object being changed has not been changed since it was last retrieved.
            // "IF-MATCH":"*", will overwrite any modification in the object, since it was last retrieved.
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            //X-HTTP-Method:  The MERGE method updates only the properties of the entity , while the PUT method replaces the existing entity with a new one that you supply in the body of the POST
            "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
            // X-RequestDigest header: When you send a POST request, it must include the form digest value in X-RequestDigest header
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
     }
</script>
```

Let me know if you need any further help. Upvote and accept it as answer if this helps.

Comment: @jason Did you try this code ?

Comment: briliant, I will give it a whirl soon - I will let you know - thanks.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks !!!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Glad that helped.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for! Used this same end point in Power Automate. Great work @Ravi