# Pnpjs how to set homepage of site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnpjs

Is there a way with pnpjs to set the homepage of a site?
basically what Set-PnPHomePage commandlet does

I can create a site, web, client side page, add controls to that page with pnpjs, but I cant see any way to set the homepage/Welcome page.

Any help greatly appreciated!
-Powell

Comment: Check this REST API solution: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271996/set-make-homepage-rest-api. maybe you can replicate it with [PnP JS Webs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/webs/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Really hoping to do with pnpjs, and that I have missed the implementation details somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the link provided in comments above, you can use `web` object to update the home page (`WelcomePage` of the SharePoint site.

Use PnP JS code like below:

```
import { spfi } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/folders/web";

const sp = spfi(...);

const result = await sp.web.rootFolder.update({ 
    WelcomePage: "SitePages/home.aspx" 
});
```

**Documentation**: [@pnp/sp/webs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/webs/)

Payload/Properties referred from this post: [Set Make Homepage - REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271996/set-make-homepage-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

Can do it with PnP JS like so:

```
await sp.web.rootFolder.update({WelcomePage:"SitePages/NewHomePage.aspx"});
```